# Is it known to whom Data was referring when he told the Borg Queen of his most recent intimate experience?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg, first-contact

In Star Trek: First Contact, the Borg Queen comes on to Data and asks him when the last time he was intimate and he states how long it has been for him - is it known to whom he was referring? Based on the amount of time he states, it is possible or likely that he is referring to Tasha Yar?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**UPDATE:** After checking my [star dates](http://home.earthlink.net/%7Ealpha-quadrant/stardate.html) (and perhaps someone can verify this) it seems that it is **not** likely that Data is referring to [Tasha Yar](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tasha_Yar)...

To start, here is the quote from [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117731/quotes) (a full transcript can be found [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie8.html)):

> **BORG QUEEN:** Are you familiar with physical forms of pleasure?
>
> **DATA:** If you are referring to sexuality, I am... fully functional, programmed in... multiple techniques.
>
> **BORG QUEEN:** How long since you've used them?
>
> **DATA:** Eight years, seven months, sixteen days, four minutes, twenty-two...
>
> **BORG QUEEN:** Far too long.

The episode ["The Naked Now"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Naked_Now_%28episode%29) is when Data and Tasha were, ahem, "intimate", and that episode occurred on/around star date 41209.2. This corresponds to March 17th, 2364.

The movie [*First Contact*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact) occurred on/around star date 50893.5. This corresponds to November 23rd, 2373.

Now, if I subtract 8 years, 7 months, and 16 days from the date of *First Contact*, I get a date of April 7th, 2365, which **is not** the same as the date when Data and Tasha had relations. This corresponds to a star date of about 42264.4, meaning that Data's last usage of his "multiple techniques" was somewhere between the episodes ["Where Silence has Lease"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Where_Silence_Has_Lease_%28episode%29) (star date 42193.6) and ["Elementary, Dear Data"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Elementary,_Dear_Data_%28episode%29) (star date 42286.3).

Could Data have been "practicing" his techniques all by his lonesome? I would rather not speculate, but if we're looking for an *in-universe* explanation then the dates suggest it *can't* be Tasha Yar that he is referring to, unless he's into necrophilia. ;)

The most likely explanation is an out-of-universe one, suggested in a comment by [Russell Borogove](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2764/russell-borogove):

> Most likely, the First Contact script writer, working in 1995, checked
> that The Naked Now aired in 1987, called that eight years, and added
> arbitrary month, day, etc.

So, it likely *is* Tasha that Data is referring to (since there is no evidence of any other intimate encounters), but the script writers just got their in-universe and out-of-universe dates mixed up.

Comment: hm, I thought the line went "sixteen days, *four* minutes, twenty-two..."

Comment: @KyleCronin Good point. 3 Minutes is almost a life time for an android.

Comment: @Kyle: The IMDB quote says 4, so that's what I'll go with. ;)

Comment: What about that TNG episode where a random crewmember and Data try to date? (And then she dumps him because she figures out she's not really into robots.)

Comment: I will accept this BUT WHO WAS HE INTIMATE WITH? The answer must be somewhere.

Comment: S4E25 "[In Theory](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/In_Theory)" on star date 44932.3 (2367) ... nope, had to be someone else.

Comment: The stardate calculator you link to isn't blessed by Paramount, so we can assume that Trek writers don't care about the conversion function it uses. Most likely, the First Contact script writer, working in 1995, checked that The Naked Now aired in 1987, called that eight years, and added arbitrary month, day,  etc. Because a highly advanced AI like Data couldn't possibly ever learn that casual conversation rarely requires high precision.

Comment: @Russell: I had the same thought, that this was an out-of-universe time measurement made during development of the script or while filming. That would explain such a glaring discrepancy, if we are to assume he is referencing his rendezvous with Tasha. Another possibility: Data's positronic net is susceptible to the time dilation from all that warp-speed traveling. ;)

Comment: Unless data spent a lot of time on the holodeck as Sherlock...

Comment: Yeah I think Data was reffering to Tasha Yar in that scene. The writers where just a little out with their dates/timing.

Comment: I'm surprised benzado's comment hasn't gotten more attention.  Data's response was referring to the **last** time that he used them.  Data's relationship with Jenna occurred after his relationship with Tasha, so that seems to be the best in-universe fit (contradicting stardate conversions not withstanding) available in canon.  There may have been someone else after Jenna, but I believe that to our knowledge Tasha definitely occurred before.

Answer (score 6):

Another candidate is Lt Jenna D'Sora - but that was only 6 years before the movie (in-universe time): http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/In_Theory_%28episode%29 - also, it is unknown if he was 'intimate' with her  in the way implied by the movie (we only see them kissing, rather unpassionately).