# Did Data and Tasha Yar's 'relationship' continue after the polywater incident?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

In [*The Naked Now*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Naked_Now_%28episode%29), Tasha and Data have a 'moment' together whilst under the effects of the polywater virus. Later on we see he still has a holo-statue of her. Clearly he has 'feelings' for her (of some kind), even after she had

> Passed away.

Did their relationship ever continue, even if as just close friends?

Comment: It definitely continued as good friends, in her memorial speech Tasha calls Data "My good friend".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It didn't continue romantically: at the end of *The Naked Now*, Tasha tells him, "I'm only going to say this once: It never happened", and as a result, when he is asked to explain why he has the holo-statue of her (in *The Measure of a Man*), he initially demurs.

As NominSim comments above, they were good friends at the time of Tasha's death, but it's never indicated that this is a result of, or continuation of, the events of *The Naked Now*. Most of the series' protagonists seem to become good friends early on.

Answer (score 6):

It definitely continued as good friends, in her [memorial speech](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPE2yaNP9hY&feature=youtu.be&t=3m22s) Tasha calls Data "my friend". As far as canonical evidence towards their physical relationship continuing, I do not recall any.

As per [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5662/4383) Data's last known intimacy that he talks to the Borg queen about, is likely Tasha, however the star dates given by the writers were likely mixed up (as it is a date *after* she died).

There is most likely, though I refuse to research it probably plenty of "fanfic" dedicated to this subject, however as far as straight from the canonical sources, I do not believe anything is said about their physical relationship continuing, in fact Tasha I believe remarks to Data that "it never happened" at the end of the episode in question. That coupled with her speaking of him as a "friend" in her memorial speech, puts him squarely in the "[friend-zone](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/JustFriends)" (obligatory TV-Tropes warning) I am afraid.

Comment: Lol @ "plenty of fanfic dedicated to this subject". I'm assuming 99.9% of it is wholly NSFW :-)